# Using two non-namespaced classes of the same name in the same page

Tags: php, namespaces

I am trying to embed a web application which contains a non-namespaced class `foo` within a website, but the surrounding GUI of the website also already loads a non-namespaced class called `foo`.

I am able to amend how the GUI is loaded, e.g. loading it into a namespace somehow, though I cannot change the files within it. Similarly, I do not have control over the web application codebase.

Is this actually possible, using the namespace / use keywords? I'm not clear what I can change within the GUI loading to make this work while still leaving the web application non-namespaced.

Here is a minimised testcase:

GUI gui.php, normally loaded using auto_prepend_file

```
# Site GUI, which includes a "foo.php" file that has no namespacing at present
require_once ('/path/to/foo.php');
echo foo::menu (array ('Menu item 1', 'Menu item 2'));
echo '<hr />';
```

Web application within page:

```
# GUI of website, normally auto-prepended but shown here explicitly for clarity
require_once ('gui.php');  // which will therefore load /path/to/foo.php

# Embedded web application, which has a different "foo.php" file that has no namespacing
require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');
foo::someFunction();
```

The result currently is:

```
- Menu item 1
- Menu item 2
___________________________

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method foo::someFunction() in ...
```

presumably because `foo::someFunction()` doesn't exist in the GUI's `foo` which is already loaded.

How can I namespace/use the loading of the **first** of these (the GUI), essentially to isolate that, without needing to modify the web application (which I don't control)?

Comment: If you have control over the auto-loader used by the GUI, you can modify it to dynamically rename the foo class when it's loaded. This approach uses stream_wrapper_register to intercept file includes and modify the class name on the fly.